# rearranging an array of data without using temporary array

Tags: arrays, permutation

How can I rearrange an array if I know where to put each element in array without using temporary array?

I guess, This has something to do with cyclic permutation but I cannot figure out how they can be linked each other. Wiki page seems irrelevant to me(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_permutation)

Comment: What do you mean by "rearrange"? Do you want to sort it into order? Shuffle it randomly?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want, please clarify by sample. You have something in your mind and then you link some irrelevant link, really you want to us guess what you want?

Comment: Not exactly. It could be some kind of sorting, but not necessarily 

Let's put it this way: I exactly know where each element should be placed in array(like hashing), How can I do this just iterating array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know both where to put each element in the array, and also which element of the array belongs at a specific index, then you can use that information to optimise your rearrangement. Otherwise you can iterate over all the array elements exchanging them into the correct location until they are all correctly placed.

```
void permuteObjects(Object[] elements, int[] positions)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
    while (positions[i] != i) {
      swapObjects(elements, i, positions[i]);
      swapIntegers(positions, i, positions[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can boil down the "re-arrangement" of your array to single permutations, i.e. to swapping the values of two elements then you can use the [XOR to perform the swap without additional variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm).

Here a sample code from the linked Wikipedia article:

```
 void xorSwap (int *x, int *y) {
     if (x != y) {
         *x ^= *y;
         *y ^= *x;
         *x ^= *y;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a temporary array and terminate it by setting it to null?

<strike>Maybe take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

HashMaps dynamicly increase when adding new items.

Use like this:

`HashMap<Integer, WhatEverYouWantToStore> = new HashMap<Integer, WhatEverYouWantToStore>();`</strike>

Comment: Actually, my array is fixed sized. I won't insert anything into it, just try to rearrange it according to a function(It could be a function that returns LSB of the element, in fact it is not important what the function is but returning an array distinct subscript for each element)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:
`import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Collection;

import java.util.Collections;

import java.util.Iterator;

import java.util.List;



public class sort {



        public static void main(String[] args) {

                List list = new ArrayList();

                String country[] = { "India", "Japan", "USA", "UK", "Nepal" };

                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

                        list.add(country[i]);

                }

                Collections.sort(list);

                Iterator i = list.iterator();



                while (i.hasNext()) {

                        System.out.print(i.next() + "\t");

                }

        }

}`